# I want the select statement to run 10x (Loop), but there is a error message that says incorrect syntax.. where did I go wrong?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, join

```
DECLARE @tagincrement INT
SET @tagincrement = 1
WHILE (@tagincrement <10)
BEGIN

SELECT tagtrack.[Asset ID], tagtrack.[UpdatedDateTime], tagstatus.[Asset ID], tagstatus.[Zone], tagstatus.[UpdatedDateTime]
FROM tagtrack 
INNER JOIN tagstatus ON tagtrack.[Asset ID]=tagstatus.[Asset ID]
WHERE tagtrack.UpdatedDateTime=
(SELECT MAX(UpdatedDateTime) FROM tagtrack WHERE [Asset ID]='10/0'+Convert(varchar, @tagincrement)

SET @tagincrement=@tagincrement+1;

END
GO
```

Error message:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 12 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'SET'.

I am able to get a output when I run the query manually specifying the [Asset ID]

```
SELECT tagtrack.[Asset ID], tagtrack.[UpdatedDateTime], tagstatus.[Asset ID], tagstatus.[Zone], tagstatus.[UpdatedDateTime]
FROM tagtrack 
INNER JOIN tagstatus ON tagtrack.[Asset ID]=tagstatus.[Asset ID]
WHERE tagtrack.UpdatedDateTime=
(SELECT MAX(UpdatedDateTime) FROM tagtrack **WHERE [Asset ID]='10/01'**

=> result of my select command

10/01   2017-06-16 16:17:33.523   10/01   U   2017-06-16 16:17:33.000
```

What I want to do is to get multiple rows of this, of different [asset id]

Comment: It would surprise me if the SELECT statement gave you a result with the missing bracket. If I parse your standalone statement in a Query Window I already get the error message: `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near '*'.`

Comment: It would be good practice to start using statement terminators, too ;)

Answer (score 2):

The error message is telling you where the error is: near the `SET` on line 12.

You are missing a closing bracket at the end of the sub-query in the `WHERE` clause on the line before.

Comment: Thank you. Was cracking my head for quite some time over this..